# What are the possible problems with unit testing ASP.NET MVC code in the following way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I've been looking at the way unit testing is done in [the NuGetGallery](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/blob/master/Facts/Services/MessageServiceFacts.cs). I observed that when controllers are tested, service classes are mocked. This makes sense to me because while testing the controller logic, I didn't want to be worried about the architectural layers below. After using this approach for a while, I noticed how often I was running around fixing my mocks all over my controller tests when my service classes changed. To solve this problem, without consulting people that are smarter than me, I started writing tests like this (don't worry, I haven't gotten that far):

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private readonly LESRepository _repository;

    public PersonController(LESRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var model = _repository.GetAll<Person>()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        var viewModel = new VMPerson(model);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}

public class PersonControllerTests
{
    public void can_get_person()
    {
        var person = _helper.CreatePerson(username: "John");
        var controller = new PersonController(_repository);
        controller.FakeOutContext();

        var result = (ViewResult)controller.Index(person.Id);
        var model = (VMPerson)result.Model;
        Assert.IsTrue(model.Person.Username == "John");
    }
}
```

I guess this would be integration testing because I am using a real database (I'd prefer an inmemory one). I begin my test by putting data in my database (each test runs in a transaction and is rolled back when the test completes). Then I call my controller and I really don't care how it retrieves the data from the database (via a repository or service class) just that the Model to be sent to the view must have the record I put into the database aka my assertion. The cool thing about this approach is that a lot of times I can continue to add more layers of complexity without having to change my controller tests:

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private readonly LESRepository _repository;
    private readonly PersonService _personService;

    public PersonController(LESRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _personService = new PersonService(_repository);
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var model = _personService.GetActivePerson(id);
        if(model  == null)
          return PersonNotFoundResult();

        var viewModel = new VMPerson(model);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Now I realize I didn't create an interface for my PersonService and pass it into the constructor of my controller. The reason is 1) I don't plan to mock my PersonService and 2) I didn't feel I needed to inject my dependency since my PersonController for now only needs to depend on one type of PersonService.

I'm new at unit testing and I'm always happy to be shown that I'm wrong. Please point out why the way I'm testng my controllers could be a really bad idea (besides the obvious increase in the time my tests will take to run).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm. a few things here mate.

First, it looks like you're trying to test the a controller method. Great :)

So this means, that anything the controller needs, should be mocked. This is because

1. You don't want to worry about what happens inside that dependency.
2. You can verify that the dependency was called/executed.

Ok, so lets look at what you did and I'll see if i can refactor it to make it a bit more testable.

-REMEMBER- i'm testing the *CONTROLLER METHOD*, not the stuff the controller method calls/depends upon.

So this means I don't care about the service instance or the repository instance (which ever architectural way you decide to follow).

NOTE: I've kept things simple, so i've stripped lots of crap out, etc.

#### Interface

First, we need an interface for the repository. This can be implemented as a in-memory repo, an entity framework repo, etc.. You'll see why, soon.

```
public interface ILESRepository
{
    IQueryable<Person> GetAll();
}
```

#### Controller

Here, we use the interface. This means it's really easy and awesome to use a mock `IRepository` or a real instance.

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILESRepository _repository;

    public PersonController(ILESRepository repository)
    {
       if (repository == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
       }
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var model = _repository.GetAll<Person>()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        var viewModel = new VMPerson(model);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

#### Unit Test

Ok - here's the magic money shot stuff.
First, we create some Fake People. Just work with me here... I'll show you where we use this in a tick. It's just a boring, simple list of your `POCO`'s.

```
public static class FakePeople()
{
    public static IList<Person> GetSomeFakePeople()
    {
        return new List<Person>
        {
            new Person { Id = 1, Name = "John" },
            new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Fred" },
            new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Sally" },
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have the test itself. I'm using `xUnit` for my testing framework and `moq` for my mocking. Any framework is fine, here.

```
public class PersonControllerTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void GivenAListOfPeople_Index_Returns1Person()
    {
        // Arrange.
        var mockRepository = new Mock<ILESRepository>();
        mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAll<Person>())
                                   .Returns(
                                FakePeople.GetSomeFakePeople()
                                          .AsQueryable);
        var controller = new PersonController(mockRepository);
        controller.FakeOutContext();

        // Act.
        var result = controller.Index(person.Id) as ViewResult;

        // Assert.
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        var model = result.Model as VMPerson;
        Assert.NotNull(model);
        Assert.Equal(1, model.Person.Id);
        Assert.Equal("John", model.Person.Username);

        // Make sure we actually called the GetAll<Person>() method on our mock.
        mockRepository.Verify(x => x.GetAll<Person>(), Times.Once());
    }
}
```

Ok, lets look at what I did.

First, I arrange my crap. I first create a mock of the `ILESRepository`. 
Then i say: If anyone ever calls the `GetAll<Person>()` method, well .. don't -really- hit a database or a file or whatever .. just return a list of people, which created in `FakePeople.GetSomeFakePeople()`.

So this is what would happen in the controller ...

```
var model = _repository.GetAll<Person>()
                       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

First, we ask our mock to hit the `GetAll<Person>()` method. I just 'set it up' to return a list of people .. so then we have a list of 3 `Person` objects. Next, we then call a `FirstOrDefault(...)` on this list of 3 `Person` objects .. which returns the single object or null, depending on what the value of `id` is.

Tada! That's the money shot :)

Now back to the rest of the unit test.

We `Act` and then we `Assert`. Nothing hard there.
For bonus points, I `verify` that we've actually called the `GetAll<Person>()` method, on the mock .. inside the Controller's `Index` method. This is a safety call to make sure our controller logic (we're testing for) was done right.

Sometimes, you might want to check for bad scenario's, like a person passed in bad data. This means you might never ever get to the mock methods (which is correct) so you `verify` that they were never called.

Ok - questions, class?

Comment: lol, that was awesome professor Krome. That cleared up a ton but raised some other questions. For instance, couldn't you have mocked LESRepository without creating an interface and mocking that? Should we really have an interface if we only have one implementation?

Comment: Its best practice to use interfaces instead of implementation. Loosely coupled is better then hard coupling.

Comment: Lots of the time we do just have 1 implementation. I still use interfaces because it constantly reminds me (and forces me) to think: I'm don't want to care and use the implementation of the concrete class .. but just want *something* to do something. For example: I don't want to care what `GetAll<Person>()` does. I don't even want to think about databases, etc. All I know, is that when I need to get all people I just have a list of all the people. Simple as that. Then in your example I do a `FirstOrDefault(..)` against that list. Great! Fine! I don't won't to care about the inner workings.

Comment: @daanl is all coupling bad? I thought I only had to decouple object A from object B if the required implementation of object A couldn't be determined at compile time. Should I be decoupling all objects in case at some point in the future I might want to pass in a different implementation? Right now LESRepository is the only implementation I'll ever have for the foreseeable future. Should I still decouple it by using an interface?

Comment: @Pure.Krome so you use interfaces with a single implementation not because it provides any architectural value but because it serves as a memento? I am asking these kinds of questions because I know these are the questions I'll be asked when I try to sell unit testing at my company. When I can't answer most if not all questions about a "modern" idea, everyone assumes the idea is bad. This makes sense because they are expecting me to know what I'm talking about. When the "interface per implementation" question comes up, so far I won't have a smart response.

Comment: Yep - that's it. Here's another example. I use IList<T> and IEnumerable<T> in my code *a lot*. I use IEmumberable<T> when I only need to iterate through a list. and IList<T> when I want `Count`, etc. The point is, I never care if this is an `Array` or a `List` or a special unique thingy, etc. *I don't -WANT- to care*. This is why I always use `interfaces` if I have a choice. I also get some bonus stuff thrown in :) If my code decides to go from `List` to an `Array`, my code won't break. You might not change your single instance, but you're protected if you do.

Comment: Oh, and when you mock, u've now got 2 instances, not a single instance :) So do you really have just 1 instance? sometimes, you have now have 2 :) NOTE: I don't have interfaces for my POCO's. That's a massive overkill IMO for 99% of my scenario's.

Answer (score 2):

Even when you do not plan to mock an interface, I strongly suggest you to do not hide the real dependencies of an object by creating the objects inside the constructor, you are breaking the Single Responsibility principle and you are writing un-testable code.

The most important thing to consider when writing tests is: "There is no magic key to write tests". There are a lot of tools out there to help you write tests but the real effort should be put in **writing testable code** rather than trying to *hack* our existing code to write a test which usually ends up being an integration test instead of a unit-test.

Creating a new object inside a constructor is one of the first big signals that your code is not testable.

These links helped me a lot when I was making the transition to start writing tests and let me tell you that after you start, that will become a natural part of your daily work and you will love the benefits of writing tests I can not picture myself writing code without tests anymore

Clean code guide (used in Google): http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/

To get more information read the following:

http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/

and watch this video cast from Misko Hevery

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w&feature=player_embedded

Edited:

This article from Martin Fowler explain the difference between a Classical and a Mockist TDD approach

http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

As a summary:

- Classic TDD approach: This implies to test everything you can without creating substitutes or doubles (mocks, stubs, dummies) with the exception of external services like web services or databases. The Classical testers use doubles for the external services only

  - Benefits: When you test you are actually testing the wiring logic of your application and the logic itself (not in isolation)
  - Cons: If an error occurs you will see potentially hundreds of tests failing and it will be hard to find the code responsible
- Mockist TDD approach: People following the Mockist approach will test in isolation all the code because they will create doubles for every dependency

  - Benefits: You are testing in isolation each part of your application. If an error occurs, you know exactly where it occurred because just a few tests will fail, ideally only one
  - Cons: Well you have to double all your dependencies which makes tests a little bit harder but you can use tools like AutoFixture to create doubles for the dependencies automatically

This is another great article about writing testable code

http://www.loosecouplings.com/2011/01/how-to-write-testable-code-overview.html

Comment: thanks for those links, I'll go through all of them later today. I'm pretty excited about learning proper unit testing. I just have a lot of questions. For instance, you say creating an instance of a dependency inside of the controller makes the controller impossible to unit test. But the PersonService didn't stand in the way of the tests I was trying to write for my controller.Shouldn't I write my tests first and let them drive my design rather than I use design ideas that I think makes testable code; design ideas for tests that haven't been written yet?

Comment: Well the truth is that yes the PersonService is in the way to properly "unit test" your controller. The reason is that when writing unit tests you need to have in mind your SUT (Subject Under Test) in this case your controller is your SUT therefore you should test in **isolation your SUT** if not, you are writing actually some kind of integration test. And this is the case since you are accessing the database. I'm not saying anything against integration tests they are valuable in all projects but they should complement the unit tests. -- Continue on the next comment

Comment: For instance if your project has a bunch of unit tests guaranteeing the logic of your application works in isolation and you add some integration tests to guarantee the object graphs are created correctly (perhaps testing all the components from the IoC can be resolved), that the mappings to the database are correct and the _happy paths_ of some specifications works as expected then pretty much you could say that your application works as expected. Just keep in mind that even when having hundreds of tests it doesn't mean your code does not have bugs, it means they have not being discovered yet

Comment: thanks for your feedback. So do you ever instantiate one object inside of another? You said that if an object is a SUT then all it's dependencies should be injected right? That's sounds more like a rule than a reason. I get injecting an EmailSender object into PersonService so I can mock EmailSender and not have my tests try to send emails. Or maybe injecting a Logger class so I can mock that. But I don't get injecting for instance AddressBuilder which does some kind of concatenation of a Person's address.Nor do I get injecting PersonService into my controller if I don't plan to mock it.

Comment: I still have a ways to go in understanding unit testing but I don't like doing things that I don't understand. The reason is I feel like an idiot when I'm asked why I did something and I just stare with a blank look on my face.

Comment: The reason behind exposing dependencies via constructors is: make explicit the dependencies and not hide them instantiating them manually. It is common to feel like this is an imposition before you start actually writing hundreds of tests. When you do not expose the dependency you simply can not test in isolation you SUT Why? because there is no way to double the dependency since the code itself is creating it internally therefore you will always have to test (in integration) "assuming" the internal objects work. Like I said writing tests is easy, the challenge is writing clean testable code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10627/discussion-between-jupaol-and-enamrik)

Answer (score 1):

There are some downsides.

First, when you have a test that depends on an external component (like a live database), that test is no longer really predictable.  It can fail for any number of reasons - a network outage, a changed password on the database account, missing some DLLs, etc. So when your test suddenly fails, you cannot be immediately sure where the flaw *is*.  Is it a database problem? Some tricky bug in your class?

When you can immediately answer that question just by knowing which test failed, you have the enviable quality of [defect localization](http://xunitpatterns.com/Goals%20of%20Test%20Automation.html#Defect%20Localization).

Secondly, if there *is* a database problem, all your tests that depend on it will fail at once.  This might not be so severe, since you can probably realize what the cause is, but I guarantee it will slow you down to examine each one.  Widespread failures can mask real problems, because you don't want to look at the exception on each of 50 tests.

And I know you want to hear about factors besides the execution time, but that really does matter. You want to run your tests as frequently as possible, and a longer runtime discourages that.

I have two projects: one with 600+ tests that run in 10 seconds, one with 40+ tests that runs in 50 seconds (this project does actually talk to a database, on purpose).  I run the faster test suite *much* more frequently while developing. Guess which one I find easier to work with?

All of that said, there is value in testing external components.  Just not when you're unit-testing.  Integration tests are more brittle, and slower.  That makes them more expensive.

Comment: what about using an inmemory database? Would that give me better performance and eliminate the problems you mentioned when working with a database server or do the problems you mentioned apply to inmemory databases as well

Comment: @enamrik It wouldn't really solve any problems, you just replace them with different ones.  Usually your in-memory database is not the exact same as your real database, and will not behave identically. I've used SQLite databases to tests NHibernate, and let me tell you, it does not work exactly the same as Oracle.  They're of limited, but real, use.

Comment: i get it, so even with an inmemory database, my tests could still be failing for reasons that they shouldn't. Makes sense. You gave me some more things to think about, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the database in unit tests has the following consequences:

1. **Performance**. Populating the database and accessing it is slow. The more tests you have, the longer the wait.  If you used mocking your controller tests may run in a couple of milliseconds each, compared to seconds if it was using the database directly.
2. **Complexity**. For shared databases, you'll have to deal with concurrency issues where multiple agents are running tests against the same database. The database needs to be provisioned, structure needs to be created, data populated etc.  It becomes rather complex.
3. **Coverage**. You mind find that some conditions are nearly impossible to test without mocking. Examples may include verifying what to do when the database times out. Or what to do if sending an email fails.
4. **Maintenance**. Changes to your database schema, especially if its frequent, will impact almost every test that uses the database.  In the beginning when you have 10 tests it may not seem like much, but consider when you have 2000 tests. You may also find that changing business rules and adapting the tests to be more complex, as you'll have to modify the data populated in the database to verify the business rule.

You have to ask whether it is worth it for testing business rules.  In most cases, the answer may be "no".

The approach I follow is:

1. Unit classes (controllers, service layers etc) by mocking out dependencies and simulating conditions that may occur (like database errors etc). These tests verify business logic and one aims to gain as much coverage of decision paths as possible.  Use a tool like [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) to highlight any issues you never thought of. You'll be surprised how much robust (and resilient) your application would be after fixing some of the issues PEX highlights.
2. Write database tests to verify that the ORM I'm using works with the underlying database. You'll be surprised the issues EF and other ORM have with certain database engines (and versions).  These tests are also useful to for tuning performance and reducing the amount of queries and data being sent to and from the database.
3. Write coded UI tests that automates the browser and verifies the system actually works.  In this case I would populate the database before hand with some data.  These tests simply automate the tests I would have done manually.  The aim is to verify that critical pieces still work.

Comment: so you're saying mock as much as I can until I get to the layer that's actually executing sql/linq statements and run that against a database? If so, it makes sense that I do try to have as many tests be as fast as possible rather than having 2000 tests that all hit the database.

Comment: Yes. A majority of defects in applications are often related to logic. Unless that logic exists inside stored procedures or views, you don't need a database to test it. You should aim for tests that verify only one thing. In your original tests you verify much more than the logic in your controller.