# What are some universal "clean-coding" conventions?

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions

Aside from language-specific constructs, for someone who is programming in PHP, javascript, java, and python, what are the top 10 clean coding must-do's? I would like to keep my code as clean as possible and as readable as possible. For example, what's the take on placing the function body opening bracket on the same line as the function declaration vs a new line? Also, what's the take on spacing between things for example (x==10) vs ( x == 10 )?
Any helpful hints for clean coding will be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, but this'll just start religious wars. There's no "one true way" for coding. Especially when it comes to stuff like bracket positioning. The usual rule is "conform to the standards of the project you're working on", and when starting your own project, "do what you want, but be consistent"

Comment: Yes, there's a consensus on coding styles across languages. It's not like people have been advocating different coding standards *within* languages for decades, but somehow forgot these.

Comment: [Always code as if the person who maintains your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CodeForTheMaintainer) - any other questions?

Comment: Up to Damien_The_Unbeliever for this pearl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a few that may help:

1. Give intuitive names to variables and methods
2. Use your **specific language** coding style (e.g. in Java vs C++ you
   use different style on brackets; choose according to specific
   language conventions)
3. Always put comment on what/why something is happening.
4. But don't pollute code with comments.
5. Try to integrate design patterns if you can. It helps in reusability
   and maintainance
6. Don't put everything in one method. Each method should do **one** thing
   and do it **really well** (this also makes the method easier to read/understand/test/debug)
7. Don't put hard-coded strings in your code
8. Separate application data and application code. I.e. try to not hard
   code configuration of your code.
9. Don't try to be more clever than the compiler. Write code that other
   people can understand it as well and let the compiler do any
   optimizations
10. Write code in a way that shows your intentions. Write code keeping
     in the back of your head that in 7 months you may need to debug it,
     or someone else might need to fix/enhance it. It is impossible to
     remember why you did something after 7 months (and comments are
     good but sometimes not good enough). Let alone the poor guy trying
     to fix your code

I am sure there are a lot more but I believe these can be useful in any language

Comment: Imho using comments as such is not a clean code. Code should be self-explanatory and require no comments.

Comment: This helps. Thanks. I don't agree with number 3 because well named methods, variables and single responsibility should remove the need for comments. I only comment when something unusual has been hacked in - which shouldn't really happen.

Answer (score 2):

Reference:

http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/

http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf

And check the links from this response:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10359288/1268570

Watch the clean code talks from Misko Hevery (given to the Google people)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w&feature=player_embedded

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0&feature=player_embedded

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI&feature=player_embedded

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc&feature=player_embedded

Theses are warning signs that you should avoid: (From Misko Hevery)

- new keyword in a constructor or at field declaration
- Static method calls in a constructor or at field declaration
- Anything more than field assignment in constructors
- Object not fully initialized after the constructor finishes (watch out for initialize methods)
- Control flow (conditional or looping logic) in a constructor
- Code does complex object graph construction inside a constructor rather than using a factory or builder
- Adding or using an initialization block
- Law of Demeter violation: method call chain walks an object graph with more than one dot (.)
- Adding or using singletons
- Adding or using static fields or static methods
- Adding or using static initialization blocks
- Adding or using service locators

This is a great book about writing clean code:

http://books.google.com.mx/books/about/Clean_Code.html?id=dwSfGQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: What's wrong with static methods?

Comment: Agree with @BlackBear - were you aiming for *virtual* methods?

Comment: Static methods which hold no state and cause no side effects should be easily unit testable. In fact, I consider such methods a "poor-man's" form of functional programming; you hand the method an object or value, and it returns an object or value. Nothing more. I don't see how such methods would negatively affect unit testing at all. But you have to see the whole picture...what about the methods that call the static method? If the callers are in another class then they have a dependency that needs to be decoupled to do a unit test. (Remember: static calls are non-mockable, and non-injectable)

Comment: This article explains it better than me http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/

Comment: So int.TryParse (C#) is impossible to test and maintain?

Comment: @Jupaol - but you specifically mention "Static method calls in a constructor or at field declaration" - so far as I'm aware, there's no issue with calling static methods at that point vs any other time the might be called. Whereas, there are various known issues with calling *virtual* methods from constructors or initializers...

Comment: Like I said: "Static methods which hold no state and cause no side effects should be easily unit testable" AKA Procedural programming or global state. If the static methods are used to create objects, initialize components, **requiring external dependencies or calling other static methods with this kind of behavior**, that's the problem since **"static calls are non-mockable, and non-injectable"** every time you construct an object that calls static methods like these you won't be unit testing in isolation your SUT, you would have an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in my opinion is that there is no real answer. A good rule is to stick to a convention, which usually is a reasonable convention that the community is already familiar with. I would rather suggest you a couple of books to have an idea.

For Java/C++/C#/VisualBasic you should read

[Code Complete: a practical handbook of software construction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)

On the Java-heavy side, you would get useful insight from

[Clean Code: a handbook of agile software craftmanship](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Consider that the concepts in those two books are of general validity and should not be bound to a specific language.